# Im struggling with a Discord.js loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've recently tried to run this code but it doesn't work. I'm trying to loop 'setActivity' every 10 seconds. It doesn't work for some reason

```
const tokenfile = require("./token1.json");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});

bot.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.username} is online and running!`);

  function sleep(ms) {
      bot.user.setActivity(`you everyday.`, {type : 'WATCHING'});
       await sleep(1000);
      bot.user.setActivity(`22 everyday.`, {type : 'WATCHING'});
       await sleep(1000);
      bot.user.setActivity(`232131232 everyday.`, {type : 'WATCHING'});
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve(), ms));
  }


}});

bot.login(tokenfile.token)
```

Comment: Well first sleep() doesn't seem to start ever (you didnt called it) and then thats just a bad loop. The loops seems: start sleep() > setActivity("you everyday") > start sleep() > setActivity("you everyday") > start sleep() > and so on.

Comment: And finally i think there is a limit for changing the ActivityStatus. Can't quite remember but i would do once every minute.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to create a loop, you don't have to recursively call a function you can just use javascript's `setInterval`.

Documentation here: [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: I'm still confused sadly.

Comment: In your ready event, you can replace all of the function() with setInterval(() => {})